# Como abrir um AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, alertdialog

Bem, estou aprendendo agora sobre Fragments.
Pelo o que eu entendi, fragmentos são componentes, algo que você quer repetir em diversas telas, sem ter que ficar criando várias class ou activity's.

Eu estou tentando criar um dialog, ele será utilizando em uma tela e será exibido assim que apertar um determinado botão. Eu criei todo o código do Dialog, porém eu não sei como eu faço para chamar ele na outra tela.

-**Dialogo**:

```
package com.vuforia.samples.Books.Neoris.Componentes;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;

public class DialogoStartGPS extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_start_gps)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.permitir, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

- **AboutScreen.java[TELA QUE SERÁ EXIBIDA O DIALOGO]**:

/*===============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2016 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other 
countries.
===============================================================================*/

```
package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList;

import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.Neoris.Componentes.DialogoStartGPS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class AboutScreen extends Activity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private String mClassToLaunch;
    private String mClassToLaunchPackage;

    private AlertDialog alertGPS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mClassToLaunchPackage = getPackageName();
        mClassToLaunch = mClassToLaunchPackage + "." + extras.getString("ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH");

        alertGPS = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogoStartGPS.class);
        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alertGPS.show();

               /* Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName(mClassToLaunchPackage, mClassToLaunch);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();*/
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma variável do tipo `DialogoStartGPS`, que criastes, no qual estende a classe `DialogFragment`. Logo depois use a o método `show` para que seja lançado na tela passando como parâmetro `getFragmentManager` e uma *string*. Veja como:

```
DialogoStartGPS dialogGPS = new DialogoStartGPS();
dialogGPS.show(getFragmentManager(), "Jon Snow!");
```

Isso usando as *libs* `android.app.Dialog` e `android.app.DialogFragment`. Veja como deve ficar:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DialogoStartGPS extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Um teste qualquer")
                .setPositiveButton("Permitir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: então eu inseri assim no meu AboutScreen.java, porém ele pede para criar um metodo na tela do meu Fragmento assim: public void show(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String s) { }

MEU CÒDIGO:
mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               DialogoStartGPS dsg = new DialogoStartGPS();
                dsg.show(getFragmentManager(), "Jon Snow");

           
            }
        });

Comment: @ThiagoSaad você precisa inserir dentro do botão na sua classe `AboutScreen`, porém da forma que fiz no `DialogStartGPS` usando as libs `android.app.Dialog` e `android.app.DialogFragment`

Comment: @ThiagoSaad substitui sua classe `DialogoStartGPS`  por essa que compartilhei na resposta, usando as libs que mencionei.

Comment: Deu erro @acklay, assim que eu clico no botão. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 3646
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui! tive que tirar o tal de .v4 e .v7

Comment: @ThiagoSaad beleza! Precisar, estou por aqui!